# How can I clear image cache with docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

I have an intermediate image that stays cached which doesn't work for me because I need to clone a github repo on each build.  How can I clear this?

Answer (score 3):

To clear the cache, I ended up running the following command:

```
docker-compose -f ../bin/docker-compose-dev.yaml build --force-rm --no-cache && docker-compose -f ../bin/docker-compose-dev.yaml up
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this [thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-delete-cache/5753/2), you can delete all images, networks and more.

```
docker system prune -a
```

NOTE: I post it here, as the above answer wasn't enough to fix my cache issue.